# Loading local html/css/js files with CefSharp v65

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am trying to load local html/css/js files using CefSharp v65 in WinForms.

I found other stack overflow posts regarding this but none of them used the new built-in version of `FolderSchemeHandlerFactory`, instead implementing their own version. Here is the documentation I read on the Scheme Handler: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage under the "Scheme Handler" header.

Sources: [Working with locally built web page in CefSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697613/working-with-locally-built-web-page-in-cefsharp)

I tried using the new feature like so:

```
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

    public void InitBrowser()
    {            
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
        {
            SchemeName = "localfolder",
            SchemeHandlerFactory = new FolderSchemeHandlerFactory(
                rootFolder: @"..\..\..\..\CEFSharpExample\webpage",
                defaultPage: "index.html" // default
            )
        });

        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        string html = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\..\webpage\index.html");
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        browser.LoadHtml(html);
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }
```

However, I am simply getting the html with no css, with no exceptions in the debugger. Does anyone understand how to leverage the new built-in functionality?

Comment: Assuming you are using WinForms, remove the call to LoadHtml and pass the start url into the ChromiumWebBrowser constructor, something like localfolder://anydomain.example/

Comment: LoadHtml with a single param loads a data uri https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Comment: @amaitland that did the trick!! Can you explain why? (for me and anyone who views this in the future)

Comment: Your requests weren't being made to the scheme handler as you were loading a data URI.

Comment: If you have time please post your updated code as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pointed out by amaitland in the comments, my "requests weren't being made to the scheme handler as [I was] loading a data URI".

My updated, working code is as follows (a little more fleshed out in case you were wondering where everything was taking place):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitBrowser();
}

public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

public void InitBrowser()
{
    var settings = new CefSettings();

    settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
    {
        SchemeName = "localfolder",
        DomainName = "cefsharp",
        SchemeHandlerFactory = new FolderSchemeHandlerFactory(
            rootFolder: @"C:\CEFSharpExample\webpage",
            hostName: "cefsharp",
            defaultPage: "index.html" // will default to index.html
        )
    });

    Cef.Initialize(settings);

    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("localfolder://cefsharp/");

    this.Controls.Add(browser);
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;   
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a single HTML file located in the resource folder?